# How to delete remote branch with dots in the name

Tags: git, github

The branch exists, but the naming seems to be causing trouble

```
manu-mac:culture-hub manu$ git push origin :12.05.1
error: dst refspec 12.05.1 matches more than one.
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:delving/culture-hub.git'
```

Comment: don't you have also a tag named 12.05.1?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably have a tag named with the same name, you need to disambiguate with an explicit reference named on the remote:

```
git push origin :refs/heads/12.05.1
```